# Have I simplified this integral correctly?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, solution-verification

I was trying to evaluate this integral for $n\in \Bbb R:$

$$ I_n=\int_0^n ne^{\frac{1}{\log(x/n)}}~dx$$

But I could not find a way (except for $n=1$). Wolfram Alpha found a closed form for $n=1$ but failed to find any other closed forms.

Then I observed that the integral could be simplified to:

$$I_n=n^2\int_0^1 e^{\frac{1}{\log(x)}}~dx $$

And so $I_n$ is a parabola multiplied by a constant, and a closed form is found.

> Is my simplification step valid?

Comment: This seems right according to Desmos.

Comment: Please, remember that in this forum you're expected to share your work. Instead of telling us that you "observed that can be simplified" show the simplification process

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_0^1e^{\frac1{\log(x)}}\mathrm dx = 2 K_1(2)\approx0.279731763633044854569197614$ where $K_1(x)$ is a modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Comment: @jjagmath I will keep that in mind going forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: This answer is short but it is all that is necessary to respond to the question.

Your simplification is correct, which follows from substituting $u=\frac xn$, $dx=ndu$.